# What is the angle of vector between two points/cordinates

Tags: c#, math, angle

Does anyone know how to get an angle between two points when 0 degree reference is up (at 12 o'clock)?
I'm using two sets of (x,y) points for `atan2()` for that but it returns 0 degree at 3 o'clock.

Comment: There are no angles between points. Angles are between vectors or lines

Comment: Two points do not define an angle. Also in what coordinate system are the points specified? Do you mean the angle between the two vectors from the origin to your two points given in Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: For clarification, the OP is visualizing a set of axis with the 'two points' as points on 2 lines that start at the center

Answer (score 4):

Atan2() returns the counterclockwise angle from the positive X axis.

If you want the clockwise angle from the positive Y axis, you can subtract that angle from 90 degrees.

Comment: And don't forget to convert from radians to degrees if required.

Comment: It does not tell me really much :P

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the horizontal and vertical positions of your points ?

If so, I will name them (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2) (X being horizontal and Y vertical)

You can calulate the position of the point #2 relative to the position of #1 :
X = X2 - X1
Y = Y2 - Y1
you can use atan( X / Y ) to get the angle you want.

You also want to check if Y == 0, because you won't be able to do X / Y.
if Y == 0, then your line is horizontal.

PS : It is quite strange to speak about the angle of two points.

Comment: It's perfectly natural for non-math people to speak about angle between two points. In this case, he's asking for an angle with a certain reference direction. The angle is between the reference line and a vector made by 2 points